# Warehouse movements proposal (Combine two tables and fullfill) - Only by SQL Cursor?

Tags: sql, database-cursor

I have separated all the products of a company per warehouse in two db tables (givers and takers) with a certain logic that gives ranks to each record to be proccessed by its priority.
I have ended up with two tables. The first table contains the givers and the second table contains the takers

I am strugling to create a result that will serially propose the needed movements from givers to takers. Is this only possible to be handled by SQL Cursor ? Can i have the result without using a Cursor because its complicate for me? Any help would be apreciated ..

GIVERS TABLE

| Product | QtyAllowedToGive | Warehouse_ID_Giver | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 30 | 100 | 1 |
| A | 30 | 101 | 2 |
| A | 10 | 102 | 3 |
| B | 10 | 200 | 4 |
| B | 6 | 201 | 9 |
| D | 5 | 300 | 10 |

TAKERS TABLE

| Product | QtyAllowedToTake | Warehouse_ID_Taker | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 50 | 200 | 1 |
| A | 5 | 203 | 2 |
| A | 11 | 202 | 3 |
| B | 16 | 202 | 4 |
| B | 3 | 202 | 5 |
| C | 10 | 300 | 6 |

RESULTS NEEDED

| Product | QtyToMove | Warehouse_ID_Giver | Warehouse_ID_Taker |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 30 | 100 | 200 |
| A | 20 | 101 | 200 |
| A | 5 | 101 | 203 |
| A | 5 | 101 | 202 |
| A | 6 | 102 | 202 |
| B | 10 | 200 | 202 |
| B | 9 | 201 | 202 |

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Is using a CURSOR a must; it could be done with a loop in Oracle or SqlServer (as examples). Cursor would also work. Could you please provide usable data (text), not images?

Comment: You also need to provide rules around partial fulfilment; ie if the taker wants 100 and the giver has 50, do we look for a different giver with >= 100 or take 50 from this one and keep looking (and the other way around)?

Comment: Hi Tina! , I provided text data. The RDBS is (Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Feb 23 2022 11:32:53   Copyright (C) 2021 Microsoft Corporation ) . No need about rules for partial fullfilment at the time .. Just serial fullfilment based on the given rank. I am trying to avoid using a cursor because its complicated from me but without cursor it still struggles me!

Comment: Warehouse  200 was allowed to take 50 units of Product A but ended up with 80,  are the expected results correct?

Comment: You are so right. It was misstyping. I Corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
drop table #Givers
select *
into #Givers
from (values 
 ('A',  30, 100,    1)
,('A',  30, 101,    2)
,('A',  10, 102,    3)
,('B',  10, 200,    4)
,('B',  6,  201,    9)
,('D',  5,  300,    10)
) T(Product,QtyAllowedToGive,   Warehouse_ID_Giver, [Rank])
drop table #Takers
select *
into #Takers
from (values 
 ('A',  50, 200,    1)
,('A',  5,  203,    2)
,('A',  11, 202,    3)
,('B',  16, 202,    4)
,('B',  3,  202,    5)
,('C',  10, 300,    6)
) T(Product,    QtyAllowedToTake,   Warehouse_ID_Taker, [Rank])


declare TakerCursor cursor fast_forward for
   select Product, QtyAllowedToTake, WareHouse_ID_Taker  from #Takers order by  Product, [Rank];
declare GiverCursor cursor fast_forward for
   select Product, QtyAllowedToGive, WareHouse_ID_Giver from #Givers order by Product, [Rank];

declare @TakerProduct char(1)='', @QtyAllowedToTake integer=0, @WareHouseID_Taker integer=0; 
declare @GiverProduct char(1)='', @QtyAllowedToGive integer=0, @WareHouseID_Giver integer=0; 

open TakerCursor
open GiverCursor

fetch next from TakerCursor into @TakerProduct, @QtyAllowedToTake, @WareHouseID_Taker;
if @@FETCH_STATUS<>0 return -- no more Takers
fetch next from GiverCursor into @GiverProduct, @QtyAllowedToGive, @WareHouseID_Giver;
if @@FETCH_STATUS<>0 return -- no more Givers

declare @QtyToMove integer=0
declare @Output table (Product char(1), Warehouse_ID_Giver integer, WareHouse_ID_Taker integer, Qty integer);
while 1=1 begin

  if @TakerProduct=@GiverProduct begin
     if @QtyAllowedToTake<=@QtyAllowedToGive
        set @QtyToMove=@QtyAllowedToTake
     else
       set @QtyToMove=@QtyAllowedToGive 
    
     insert into @Output (Product, Warehouse_ID_Giver, WareHouse_ID_Taker, Qty)
        Select Product=@TakerProduct
              --, QtyAllowedToTake=@QtyAllowedToTake, QtyAllowedToGive=@QtyAllowedToGive, 
              , Giver=@WareHouseID_Giver
              , Taker=@WareHouseID_Taker
              , Qty=@QtyToMove;

     set @QtyAllowedToTake=@QtyAllowedToTake-@QtyToMove
     set @QtyAllowedToGive=@QtyAllowedToGive-@QtyToMove

     if @QtyAllowedToGive=0 begin
         fetch next from GiverCursor into @GiverProduct, @QtyAllowedToGive, @WareHouseID_Giver;
         if @@FETCH_STATUS<>0 break -- no more Givers
     end
     if @QtyAllowedToTake=0 begin
        fetch next from TakerCursor into @TakerProduct, @QtyAllowedToTake, @WareHouseID_Taker;
        if @@FETCH_STATUS<>0 break -- no more Takers
     end
  end else
  if @TakerProduct>@GiverProduct begin
     fetch next from GiverCursor into @GiverProduct, @QtyAllowedToGive, @WareHouseID_Giver;
     if @@FETCH_STATUS<>0 break -- no more Givers
  end else
  if @TakerProduct<@GiverProduct begin
     fetch next from TakerCursor into @TakerProduct, @QtyAllowedToTake, @WareHouseID_Taker;
     if @@FETCH_STATUS<>0 break -- no more Takers
  end
end
close GiverCursor
close TakerCursor
deallocate GiverCursor
deallocate TakerCursor
select * from @Output
```

No error checking or tidying up, or optimising.

Comment: Tinazmu, it works like a charm !! You are amazing !