# Row pairing according to FIFO logic in SQL Server 2018

Tags: sql, sql-server, fifo

I need to pair sales orders with purchase orders using FIFO (first in, first out) logic.

In the first table, I have sales orders arranged in ascending order (the SO_RowId and SO_CreationDate columns tell us about the order).

In the second table, I have purchase orders also arranged in ascending order (the PO_RowId and PO_CreationDate columns tell us about the order).

The third table (FINAL TABLE) presents the pairing result, i.e. the result I want to get but I don't know how to approach it.

TABLE 1 (Sales orders)

| SO_RowId | SO_Quantity | SO_CreationDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | 6 | 2022-03-03 |
| 3 | 2 | 2022-03-03 |
| 4 | 6 | 2022-04-01 |
| 5 | 3 | 2022-05-01 |

TABLE 2  (Purchase orders)

| PO_RowId | PO_Quantity | PO_CreationDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-01-05 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-03-03 |
| 3 | 4 | 2022-03-14 |
| 4 | 7 | 2022-04-01 |
| 5 | 20 | 2022-04-01 |

FINAL TABLE (the result I need)

| SO_RowId | SO_Quantity | SO_CreationDate | PO_RowId | PO_Quantity | PO_CreationDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-01-01 | 1 | 2 | 2022-01-05 |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2 | 1 | 2022-03-03 |
| 1 | 4 | 2022-01-01 | 3 | 4 | 2022-03-14 |
| 1 | 7 | 2022-01-01 | 4 | 7 | 2022-04-01 |
| 1 | 6 | 2022-01-01 | 5 | 6 | 2022-04-01 |
| 2 | 6 | 2022-03-03 | 5 | 6 | 2022-04-01 |
| 3 | 2 | 2022-03-03 | 5 | 2 | 2022-04-01 |
| 4 | 6 | 2022-04-01 | 5 | 6 | 2022-04-01 |
| 5 | 3 | 2022-05-01 | - | - | - |

I start pairing with the oldest sales order (SO_RowId=1). SO_Quantity is 20 and I'm looking for the oldest purchase order (PO_RowId=1).
On the oldest purchase order, I have a quantity of 2, so in the final table, I first create a row with SO_Quantity=2 and PO_Quantity=2.

| SO_RowId | SO_Quantity | SO_CreationDate | PO_RowId | PO_Quantity | PO_CreationDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-01-01 | 1 | 2 | 2022-01-05 |

There are still 18 items left from the first sales order (SO_RowId=1), so I'm looking for the next oldest purchase order (SO_RowId=2) that has a quantity of 1 available (PO_Quantity=1).
 After that in the final table I create a row again with SO_RowId=1 but with SO_Quantity=1 and PO_RowId=2 and PO_RowId=1.

| SO_RowId | SO_Quantity | SO_CreationDate | PO_RowId | PO_Quantity | PO_CreationDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-01-01 | 1 | 2 | 2022-01-05 |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2 | 1 | 2022-03-03 |

There are still 17 left to pair from the first sale order...

I hope I have conveyed the essence of pairing well.
The pairing process can be seen in more detail in the example I prepared above

I also prepared tables with data:

```
--Sales orders
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1]
(
    SO_RowId int,
    SO_Quantity decimal(15,4),
    SO_CreationDate datetime
)

INSERT [dbo].[table1] (SO_RowId,SO_Quantity,SO_CreationDate)
VALUES
(1,20,'20220101'),
(2,6,'20220303'),
(3,2,'20220303'),
(4,6,'20220401'),
(5,3,'20220501')

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table1]



--Purchase orders
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table2]
(
    PO_RowId int,
    PO_Quantity decimal(15,4),
    PO_CreationDate datetime
)

INSERT [dbo].[table2] (PO_RowId,PO_Quantity,PO_CreationDate)
VALUES
(1,2,'20220105'),
(2,1,'20220303'),
(3,4,'20220314'),
(4,7,'20220401'),
(5,20,'20220401')

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table2]
```

Table data is deleted daily and new data is reinserted. There may be more sales orders than purchase orders as well as more purchase orders than sales orders, but the quantity pairing algorithm should remain the same, i.e. we start pairing with the oldest sales order, which we pair with the oldest purchase order

Comment: Best done with cursors; I had an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71661991/11695049

Comment: There is **NO** SQL Server **2018** version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017, 2019 and 2022 - take your pick

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is by getting the current running total and previous running total for each table and then just building the logic into a case expression.

For example,

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (
    SO_RowId int,
    SO_Quantity decimal(15,4),
    SO_CreationDate datetime
);
INSERT @Table1 (SO_RowId,SO_Quantity,SO_CreationDate)
VALUES
(1,20,'20220101'),
(2,6,'20220303'),
(3,2,'20220303'),
(4,6,'20220401'),
(5,3,'20220501');

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (
    PO_RowId int,
    PO_Quantity decimal(15,4),
    PO_CreationDate datetime
);
INSERT @Table2 (PO_RowId,PO_Quantity,PO_CreationDate)
VALUES
(1,2,'20220105'),
(2,1,'20220303'),
(3,4,'20220314'),
(4,7,'20220401'),
(5,20,'20220401')
;

WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT *, PrevTotal = ISNULL(LAG(RunningTotal) OVER (ORDER BY SO_CreationDate, SO_RowId), 0)
    FROM (
        SELECT *, RunningTotal = SUM(SO_Quantity) OVER (ORDER BY SO_CreationDate, SO_RowId)
        FROM @Table1
    ) AS t
),
    t2 AS (
    SELECT *, PrevTotal = ISNULL(LAG(RunningTotal) OVER (ORDER BY PO_CreationDate, PO_RowId), 0)
    FROM (
        SELECT *, RunningTotal = SUM(PO_Quantity) OVER (ORDER BY PO_CreationDate, PO_RowId)
        FROM @Table2
    ) AS t
)

SELECT t1.SO_RowId,
    SO_Quantity = CASE
        WHEN t1.RunningTotal > t2.RunningTotal AND t1.PrevTotal >= t2.PrevTotal THEN t2.RunningTotal - t1.PrevTotal
        WHEN t1.RunningTotal > t2.RunningTotal AND t1.PrevTotal < t2.PrevTotal THEN t2.PO_Quantity
        WHEN t1.RunningTotal <= t2.RunningTotal AND t1.PrevTotal >= t2.PrevTotal THEN t1.SO_Quantity
        WHEN t1.RunningTotal <= t2.RunningTotal AND t1.PrevTotal < t2.PrevTotal THEN t1.RunningTotal - t2.PrevTotal
        WHEN t2.RunningTotal IS NULL THEN t1.SO_Quantity
    END,
    t1.SO_CreationDate,
    t2.PO_RowId,
    PO_Quantity = CASE
        WHEN t1.RunningTotal > t2.RunningTotal AND t1.PrevTotal >= t2.PrevTotal THEN t2.RunningTotal - t1.PrevTotal
        WHEN t1.RunningTotal > t2.RunningTotal AND t1.PrevTotal < t2.PrevTotal THEN t2.PO_Quantity
        WHEN t1.RunningTotal <= t2.RunningTotal AND t1.PrevTotal >= t2.PrevTotal THEN t1.SO_Quantity
        WHEN t1.RunningTotal <= t2.RunningTotal AND t1.PrevTotal < t2.PrevTotal THEN t1.RunningTotal - t2.PrevTotal
        WHEN t1.RunningTotal IS NULL THEN t2.PO_Quantity
    END,
    t2.PO_CreationDate
FROM t1
FULL JOIN t2
    ON t2.RunningTotal > t1.PrevTotal
    AND t2.PrevTotal <= t1.RunningTotal
    
UNION ALL -- Get leftover amount if total POs > total SOs

SELECT SO_RowId = NULL, 
       SO_RowQuantity = NULL, 
       SO_CreationDate = NULL, 
       t2.PO_RowId, 
       PO_Quantity = t2.RunningTotal - t1.RunningTotal, 
       t2.PO_CreationDate
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM t1 
    ORDER BY RunningTotal DESC
) AS t1
JOIN t2 
    ON t2.RunningTotal > t1.RunningTotal 
    AND t2.PrevTotal < t1.RunningTotal
    
UNION ALL -- Get leftover amount if total SOs > total POs

SELECT t1.SO_RowId,
       SO_RowQuantity = t1.RunningTotal - t2.RunningTotal,
       t1.SO_CreationDate,
       PO_RowId = NULL,
       PO_Quantity = NULL,
       PO_CreationDate = NULL
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM t2 
    ORDER BY RunningTotal DESC
) AS t2
JOIN t1 
    ON t1.RunningTotal > t2.RunningTotal 
    AND t1.PrevTotal < t2.RunningTotal
;
```

Edited a bit because I realised your requirements were slightly different to what I initially thought they might be. Hopefully the logic here makes sense.

Comment: Thanks @ZLK for trying to help. Your SQL script doesn't quite work properly. If we insert the following values in the first table:
INSERT Table1 (SO_RowId,SO_Quantity,SO_CreationDate)
VALUES
(1,3,'20220101'),
(2.6,'20220303'),
(3,2,'20220303'),
(4,6,'20220401'),
(5,3,'20220501');
then redundant records with value 0 appear

Comment: Are you saying you don't want redundant records? Because from the looks of your example you did want them? `5 3 2022-05-01 - - -`?

Comment: I understand what you're implying, but I need to know what sales orders were or weren't fulfilled by purchase orders. I don't need information that some purchase order didn't have a sales order assigned to it. This link is the solution to my problem stackoverflow.com/a/71661991/11695049
but thank you for your help. Your script just confirms that every problem can be solved in many ways